# CameraX Flash Issue

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

This is a weird issue . I don't know whether it is a bug or something in the library .So the issue is with flash of the camerax .

I assign a global variable flashMode

```
    private var flashMode: Int = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF
```

then set it to the ImageCaptureBuilder

```
        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .setFlashMode(flashMode)
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()
```

And before taking the picture I turn the flash On

```
if (camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() == true) {
   flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON
}
```

But this does Not turn the camera flash On , but it sets the flashMode value to 1 ,i.e.,ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON (I checked via logging ).Before capturing the image , i again logged and checked the value of flashMode and it was 1 , but then too the flash was not turning on.But if I set  the global variable as

```
private var flashMode: Int = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON
```

Then it works and the flash get's turned on .
I have tried this above method of setting the Flash On post setting it to FlashModeOff in my previous projects and it had worked well . But this time I am not able to understand what is wrong .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the flash mode with

```
imageCapture.flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON
```

instead of

```
flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using JAVA

```
private void ativarFlash() {
    ic_flash.startAnimation(animationDown);
    if (flashMode == FlashMode.ON) {
        flashMode = FlashMode.OFF;
    } else {
        flashMode = FlashMode.ON;
    }

    startCamera();
}
```

And on `startCamera();`

```
private void startCamera() {

    CameraX.unbindAll();
    preview = setPreview();
    imageCapture = setImageCapture();
    //bind to lifecycle:
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture);
    ivBitmap.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```